# Why the & operator on struct doesn't return a digital address?

Tags: go

I just started to learn the golang.

I found the `&` operator behaves differently for simple type and struct.

- For simple type, `&` returns an address.
- For struct, it returns something else.

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func main() {
    s1 := "abc"
    fmt.Println("s1 address =", &s1)

    s2 := person{"Sam", 55}
    fmt.Println("s2 address = ", &s2)

}
```

Output:

```
[ `hello` | done: 79.0079ms ]
    s1 address = 0xc04203c1e0
    s2 address =  &{Sam 55}   <======== What's this? And why not some address like above?
```

Again, is this design a `have-to` or a `happen-to`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The unitary operator `&` behaves the same for builtin types and structs, it's used to get the memory address of a var. In this case we'll see `&{Sam 55}` because Go always checks by default if the parameter in fmt.Println() is a struct or a pointer to struct and in that case will try to print each field of the struct for debugging purposes, but if you want to see a pointer you can use fmt.Printf() with `%p`, like this:

```
func main() {
    s1 := "abc"
    fmt.Println("s1 address =", &s1)

    s2 := person{"Sam", 55}

    fmt.Println("s2 as pointer =", &s2)

    fmt.Printf("s2 address = %p value with fields %+v", &s2, s2)
}
```

Bonus: you can use `%+v` to print field names and values

https://play.golang.org/p/p7OVRu8YWB

Comment: I.e. it's fmt.Println() that behaves different for a pointer to a string and a pointer to a struct.

Comment: i.e. fmt.Println will try to call a String() method and each type has a default string representation